# Can't vertical scroll page on mobile devices with full width PrimeNg carousel

Tags: html, css, primeng

I have a full width carousel on a page, most of the area of the page is covered by the carousel. On mobile screen when I try to scroll vertically, it does not work.

You can check the behavior here, try to scroll on image. https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/carousel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a solution to this issue. If we override the onTouchMove method, the scroll would start working. Because in the plugin implementation of this method default event is prevented.

```
import { Carousel } from 'primeng/carousel';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor() {
        Carousel.prototype.onTouchMove = () => { };
    }
}
```

Comment: save my life with this :)

Comment: Property 'onTouchMove' does not exist on type 'CarouselModule'.ts

Answer (score 1):

@sushil kumar code works perfectly. thanks.

```
constructor() {
    Carousel.prototype.onTouchMove = () => { };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sushil Kumar your solution helped me a lot. Thank you. I just strong typed the override method so it fits my linting rules. My code looks like this:

```
Carousel.prototype.onTouchMove = (): void => undefined;
```